# css is not loading in codeigniter 4

Tags: css, codeigniter, assets

I keep my css and js in the assets folder in the root directory of codeigniter 4 and i am trying to load my css with this line

```
   <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but my css is not loading.
this line works fine codeigniter 3 . thanks in advance .

Comment: How does this line look like in HTML output? What's your project structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855069/8544723

Comment: since codeigniter used spark serve to run project, you must put your asset to public folder, you can read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62732140/11555422 , let me know if you have another questions :)

Answer (score 0):

base_url() function already prints a '/' . So delete the slash after php tag. Like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem for codeigniter 4 to link css and js files like you.
The ci4 seems to add current path into this url, and the result becomes `[current_path]/[base_url]/assets/css/style.css` which is `http://localhost/ci/home/localhost/ci/assets/css/style.css`.

To solve this problem, I just added "http://" into base_url in "application/config/config.php". As this:

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci';`

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `base_url()`, you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, load manually in your controller:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

base_url() function returns a trailing slash by default. So no need to add '/' after base_url(). So your stylesheet link should like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
```

Or, you can also write as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>">
```

You may get help from here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Your answer is for CodeIgniter 3 and not CodeIgniter 4 I'm afraid.