# Assets won't load if base url contains port number - codeigniter 4

Tags: php, url, base-url, codeigniter-4

I am running `php spark serve` to run a codeigniter 4 app locally.

if my `$base_url` have a port number, all my assets wont load, but it will if i remove the port number

**This wont load my assets**

`public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/folder_name';`

**This will load my assets**

`public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/folder_name';`

Any suggestion as to why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i hope my answer is not late.

since codeigniter 4 used spark server and there is many update.

1. Just put your asset file to public folder

[image: Put your asset here]

2. load your asset at view for example

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('vendor/login-register/css/style.css')?>">`

it will load your asset at folder public/vendor/login-register/css/style.css

let me know if you have any question or another issues :)